# Associate and view XML files - Visual Studio

Tags: file-association, visual-studio, xml, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio can be used as an XML editor. For example, I can go to File>New>XML File. I can also create an XML file as part of a project and view it via the project manager.

Proof you can use it for XML:

[image]

However for whatever stupid reason, the VS installer does not associate XML files with Visual Studio. I've had to right click the XML file in Windows Explorer and go to "Open With" and selected VS. This for some reason then opens VS **and** opens Notepad where it then displays the XML:

[image]

How can I properly associate XML files with Visual Studio so they actually open in Visual Studio and not Notepad? Is this a bug perhaps?

Comment: FWIW I use VS Pro 2013, and using "Open With..", and/or assigning XMLs to open in VS works as expected.  You'll need to do some trouble-shooting... Log in as a different user and try it again, if it behaves as you want, then it's something whacky about your user account, if it doesn't (and still opens Notepad), then it's something wacky about your OS and/or VS install.  Come back and edit into your question what you tried and what the results were.